# Getting Error While Save

Tags: datetimecontrol

In my webpart, I have added a SharePoint datetime control

```
DateTimeControl dateTimeControl = new DateTimeControl();
dateTimeControl.ID = "dateTimeControl";
dateTimeControl.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;

this.Controls.Add(dateTimeControl);
```

But getting below error while click on save button

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Hour, Minute, and Second parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
>    at System.DateTime..ctor(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second, Int32 millisecond)
>    at System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.ToDateTime(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second, Int32 millisecond, Int32 era)
>    at System.Globalization.Calendar.ToDateTime(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second, Int32 millisecond)
>    at System.DateTime..ctor(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second, Int32 millisecond, Calendar calendar)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DateTimeControl.GetDateTimeFromTextBox()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DateTimeControl.ChangesByUser(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents()
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

> "I just faced the same problem and had a closer look at what is going
>   on in the DateTimeControl that is leveraged by the DateTimeField
>   control. The problem lies in the Time component, which is rendered as
>   2 drop downs. One for the hour and one for the minutes. Unfortunately,
>   the drop-downs have selectindex = -1 during the event handling phase
>   on a postback. Consequently, -1 is passed into the hours and minutes
>   parameters of the DateTime constructor.
>
> The work-around is to disable the time component and go for a date
>   only rendering of the control by setting DateTimeField.DateOnly =
>   true"

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/64c05363-fd7e-49bb-8239-c93ec78172b6/datetime-control-using-basefieldcontrol?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: I don't think that this is a solution for me.
I dig into this problem and found that when i am selecting any date, then only it is giving me error.
If i try to save without selecting any date, it is working fine. So in my case, i have another issue. Still not able to find the solution.